# How to use yii\db\Command with postgis st_intersects query?

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2

I'm using yii\db\Command and SqlDataProvider to populate a GridView widget grid. The SqlDataProvider is working, however the GridView widget needs the count of the result set to work out the grid pagination. The count comes from the yii\db\Command which isn't working. Can anyone see a solution please?

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new postcodeSearch();
        //$dataProvider =     $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

$pc = "CB7 5UE";

$count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
                    geodata.codepoint_bng as p, geodata.river_waterbody_catchments_cycle1 as w
                    FULL OUTER JOIN geodata.wap_costs as c ON w.ea_wb_id = c.wbid
                    FULL OUTER JOIN geodata.actypes as t ON c.actype = t.actiontype
                INNER JOIN geodata.river_ecological_status_2013 as wb_ec ON w.ea_wb_id = wb_ec.wb_id
            WHERE 
                ST_Intersects(p.geom, w.geom) AND p.postcode = $pc');
//$count = 20;



$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => "SELECT 
                    w.name,
                    w.ea_wb_id, 
                    wb_ec.ecostatus, 
                    wb_ec.ecocert, 
                    t.actgroup, 
                    t.actdesc, 
                    c.anncost, 
                    c.initcost,  
                    c.comment
                FROM 
                    geodata.codepoint_bng as p, geodata.river_waterbody_catchments_cycle1 as w
                    FULL OUTER JOIN geodata.wap_costs as c ON w.ea_wb_id = c.wbid
                    FULL OUTER JOIN geodata.actypes as t ON c.actype = t.actiontype
                INNER JOIN geodata.river_ecological_status_2013 as wb_ec ON w.ea_wb_id = wb_ec.wb_id
            WHERE 
                ST_Intersects(p.geom, w.geom) AND p.postcode = '$pc'",
    'totalCount' => $count,

    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [
                        'ea_wb_id',
                        ],
                ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],

]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?
You've got 20 records and your pagination is 20 limit. So it should be 1 page only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake with quote mark (`'`->`"`) and your count query must be executed before.

```
$count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
                        geodata.codepoint_bng as p, geodata.river_waterbody_catchments_cycle1 as w
                        FULL OUTER JOIN geodata.wap_costs as c ON w.ea_wb_id = c.wbid
                        FULL OUTER JOIN geodata.actypes as t ON c.actype = t.actiontype
                    INNER JOIN geodata.river_ecological_status_2013 as wb_ec ON w.ea_wb_id = wb_ec.wb_id
                WHERE 
                    ST_Intersects(p.geom, w.geom) AND p.postcode = '$pc'")->queryScalar();
```